# LOAD CSV: mulitple MERGE and Eager operator

Tags: csv, neo4j

I have a large CSV file that contains mulitple nodes per line. I would like to use `LOAD CSV` to `MERGE` the nodes and set some properties. However, I always get the "Eager operator" warning for this query:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///MRCONSO.RRF' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
MERGE (c:Concept {cui: line[0]})
ON CREATE SET c.language = line[1]
MERGE (l:LexicalForm {lui: line[3]})
ON CREATE SET l.status = line[2];
```

When I remove the `ON CREATE` part it works but I want to merge on a specific ID, not on the combination of the ID and the other properties.

Is it possible to rephrase this somehow to avoid the Eager operator? I would like to create 6 different nodes from a single line and the alternative would be to iterate the file 6 times.

Comment: Give us a sample of your file MRCONSO.RRF. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You have an RRF file and load CSV requires a CSV line. When you reference a field in the csv you need to include the data type and your tag (line). You also need the periodic commit number of rows per iteration. Your file needs to be in the import folder of your database.

For example:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///MRCONSO.RRF' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
MERGE (c:Concept {cui: toInteger(linecui),language: toString(line.language})
```

Comment: You don't have to cast to a specific type and `PERIODIC COMMIT` has a default batch size. Also, the file ending is `.RRF` but it's a char delimited file and works with `LOAD CSV`. The question was really about avoiding the eager operator when using multiple `MERGE` statements.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your point. I have not worked with the UMLS for several years. The UMLS files are very large. Have you tried apoc.periodic.iterate ? It's solved similar problems for me. I've run into problems when not casting data when it is ambiguous because of mixed text: 1234 and A1234 in the same field. I'm just in the habit of always casting so I know what I'm getting.